# Work with a set of files in Xcode

Tags: xcode, swift, development-environment

Is there a way to make developers live easier to jump between different codes in XCode ?

How I work today, which is in my opinion not efficient:

- I have a project with about 2 Screens of files in the explorer to the left.
- I am working on part1 and I am jumping to other part of code by clicking on objects (xcode links to another file).
- To get to the previous Codepart I can select the back-icon in the browserstyle toolbar or I can select the file in the explorer.
- To search a specific part of code, I have to remember the name of function or object and search it with the search function.

What I am missing:

- A way to bookmark codelines, so I can access different code parts from one central view.
- A way to have a set of Files open, to switch between instead of selecting files in the explorer or using the searchfunction. In Eclipse you will have tabs, so there will be direct access to a set of files. In Xcode you can double click a file in explorer and it will open a new window, which is in my opinion not really usable when you have only one screen.

Does any experienced developer have a way to make my work easier ?

**UPDATE** Where are the tabs, which was mentoined in Martins comment ?

[image]

Comment: Xcode has tabs as well ...

Comment: Dear Martin. Thanks for helping me. I updated the question with an image, because I don't find the option to have tabs. Can you guide me to this. This would be very helpfull to have tabs like in Eclipse.

Comment: Cmd-T opens a new tab in my Xcode.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a lot ! Any hint about bookmarking ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Tabs: `CMD+T`

There is no way to bookmark, but you can try to enable line numbers. It is useful.

To enable line numbers: Preferences(`CMD+,`)-> Text Editing -> Show Line Nunbers.

You can use `CMD+L` to jump to any line number.